# Verify ocsp response is signed by different key than Issuing CA

Tags: pki, ocsp, ejbca

Given I have the issuing CAs pem, how would I verify the ocsp response from `openssl ocsp` is signed by a different key than the one binded to the CA? I am trying to make sure I set up my ocsp responder in EJBCA correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be tricky with openssl, it has so many options. But you should check the -CA* options. (openssl ocsp -help)

Comment: Your post does not answer the question. At best it is a comment to the question. Either update your post to answer the question or delete it.